# Сопоставление ключей вложенного словаря с ключом исходного словаря

Tags: python, сортировка, словари, список

Существует 2 словаря:
`dict1={'proxyid':nvps}` содержащий в себе данные {'10444': 1.7722, '10441': 0.01666}
и
`dict2={'hostid':proxyid}` с данными {'10084': 10445, '10443': 10441}.
Вопрос - как сделать сопоставление ключа из первого словаря с аргументом второго словаря, чтобы в дальнейшем произвести объединение двух данных словарей в один новый составной с сортировкой по ключу (proxyid) из dict1, чтобы получился вот такой вот вывод:
{'10444': {'10443': 10444},
'10441': {'10084': 10441}}

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: 1) Ну начнем с того, что словарь нельзя отсортировать. Почитайте документацию по типам данных.
2) По какому критерию Вы сопоставить хотите?

Comment: У Вас точно верный итоговый словарь? Может он должен быть таким:{'10444': {'10484': 10444},
 '10441': {'10043': 10441}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Альберт, если я правильно понял Вашу логику, то получается так:

```
d1 = {'10444': 1.7722, '10441': 0.01666}
d2 = {'10084': 10444, '10443': 10441}
d3 = {}
for key, value in d2.items():
    if str(value) in d1:
        d3[value] = {key:value}

print(d3)
```

ИТОГ:

```
{10444: {'10084': 10444}, 10441: {'10443': 10441}}
```

Либо более короткая запись:

```
d1 = {'10444': 1.7722, '10441': 0.01666}
d2 = {'10084': 10444, '10443': 10441}
d3 = {key:value for key, value in d2.items() if str(value) in d1}
print(d3)
```